# Mongoose, concise way to get one item with each unique property into an array?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a collection of documents with many different characteristics. I want to get from Mongoose an array where each item in the array is a unique value for an attribute, in this case `color`.  In other words, I do not want an array of each item, just of the color values.  So in this case, if I have 100 different products, but only 8 colors between all 100, then I would like the to have an array of the 8 colors.  Here is the way I have been using but I am wondering if there is a more concise way of doing it?

```
  var allproducts = Products.find(function (err, products) {
    // Get all products
    var collection = [];
    // Make an array to contain a product with each of the 8 colors
    var uniqueArray = [];
    // Make an array to check the current color against (if already used)
    for (var i = products.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
      if (uniqueArray.indexOf(products[i].color) === -1) {
        // Check to see if the color is in the unique color array
        uniqueArray.push(products[i].color);
        // Add it if not
        collection.push(products[i]);
        // Add the product to the collection array if its color is not in the unique array
      }
    }
  });
```

Attempting to use the Mongoose `aggregate method`:

```
router.get('/', function (req, res) {
  Products.aggregate([{
    $group: {
      _id: '$color'
    }
  }], {}, function (err, collection) {
    console.log(err, collection);
    if (err) {
      throw err
    }
    res.end();
    // res.json(collection);
  });
});
```

Comment: You might be looking for `distinct` [here](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.distinct)

Comment: This is a good way to get the individual unique colors, however I would like to get the first entire document that has each unique color.

Answer (score 1):

I. Directly in mongodb, you have to this request :

```
 db.colors.aggregate( { $group: {_id:"$color"} } )
```

Result :

```
{ "_id" : "yellow" }
{ "_id" : "blue" }
{ "_id" : "red" }
```

[MongoDB Tutorial for aggregation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/aggregation-zip-code-data-set/)

II. In mongoose you can do :

```
Products.aggregate(
     {$group: {
            _id: '$color' // grouping key - group by field district
     }
 }).exec( function( err, products ) {
    if ( err ) {
      return res.status( 400 ).send({
        message: errorHandler.getErrorMessage( err )
      });
    } else {
      res.json( products );
    }
 });
```

[Mongoose : Model aggregate](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.aggregate)

Comment: The first one works for me directly in Mongo but in Mongoose I get:
`[Error: Arguments must be aggregate pipeline operators]`

Comment: Please try :       Products.aggregate({
     $group: {
            _id: '$color' // grouping key - group by field district
     }
 }, {}, callback);  //without the [] because we have not a list of aggregate function

Comment: Oki sorry please try :   Products.aggregate(
    { $group: { _id: '$color' } }
  ).exec( function( err, data ) {
    if ( err ) {
    //
    } else {
     //
   }
  });

Comment: updated : Products.aggregate(
     {$group: {
            _id: '$color' // grouping key - group by field district
     }
 }).exec( function( err, products ) {
    if ( err ) {
      return res.status( 400 ).send({
        message: errorHandler.getErrorMessage( err )
      });
    } else {
      res.json( products );
    }
 });

Comment: Side note, backticks , these (`` ) make your inline code examples easier to read

Comment: @Startec : I updated ma first post too ;)  `Products.aggregate( {$group: { _id: '$color' // grouping key - group by field district } }).exec( function( err, products ) { if ( err ) { return res.status( 400 ).send({ message: errorHandler.getErrorMessage( err ) }); } else { res.json( products ); } }); `

Comment: This code creates an array of the distinct values.  However, I found using `distinct` is much simpler.
However, neither this nor the `distinct` command do exactly what I wanted which is to get one object with each distinct property (this just returns an array OF the distinct values).

Comment: Ok maybe you can use the join, or map functions in order to format the answer in a correct format ?

Answer (score 1):

This can be easily solved using [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs)

```
npm install lodash --save

var _ = require('lodash');

var allproducts = Products.find(function (err, products) {
    ...
    var uniqueArray = _.pluck(products, 'color');
    uniqueArray = _.uniq(uniqueArray);
    ....  
});
```